# FCM sending message from NodeJS server caused error: request contains an invalid argument

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wan't to send a push notification to our iOS/Android devices via FCM from our NodeJS server. I follow the steps from the FCM docs to add the admin SDK to our project (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). I try to send with this code a message to my Android

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("/path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
const crypto = require("crypto");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
  });

exports.sendMessage = () => {
    //let registrationToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex");
    var registrationToken = "TEST";
    var message = {
        data: {
            msg: "Hello, this is a push notification"
        },
        token: registrationToken
    };
    admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error sending message: ", err);
        })
}
```

I call this method from Postman via a HTTP GET function. But then this error occur:

```
    Error sending message:  { Error: Request contains an invalid argument.
    bla bla bla....
 errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
     message: 'Request contains an invalid argument.' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I fix my problem, the problem was that my *registrationToken* was wrong, now I can successfully send messages to my Android device.